# why does type casting to float from int prints "0.0000"

Tags: c, pointers, casting, sizeof

Below is some code that i wrote to understand typecasting but I do not understand why the value of float or double is being printed as "0.000000" even if i type cast from as array of integers or try to interpret from a union's address.

```
#include <stdio.h>

union test1
{
 int x;
 float y;
 double z;
};


int main()
{
 int x[2]={200,300};
 float *f;
 f=(float*)(x);
 printf("%f\n",*f); /*(1)why is this value 0.0*/

 *f=(float)(x[0]); /*(2)this works as expected and prints 200.00000*/
  printf("%f\n",*f);

  union test1 u;
  u.x=200;
  /*(3)this line give compilation error why*/
  //printf ("sizeof(test1) = %d \n", sizeof(test1));
  /*(4) this line also prints the value of float and double as 0.0000 why*/
  printf ("sizeof(test1) = %lu u.x:%d u.y:%f u.z:%lf \n", sizeof(u), u.x, u.y, u.z);
  return 0;
```

}

Comment: Pick a language. Different languages work differently.

Comment: Title says "0.0000".  Post says "0.000000".  Suggest changing so they match to your true experience.

Comment: Casting doesn't change the data, it only changes the type the data will be interpreted as. Do a google search on how floating point data (for your architecture of choice) is stored and you will probably understand a little better.

Comment: What you are doing is undefined behavior (UB).  Using `"%e"` will help understand the UB better, but it is still UB.

Comment: @mah: Well... not really. Casting very well changes the representation of a value. For a pointer that would be the value of the pointer itself, but not of the data it points to - which is the problem here. C does not have the zoo of different cast operators like C++.

Comment: Just a note that `*f=(float)(x[0]);` is also undefined, as `f` doesn't point to a float value. So it doesn't "work as expected" even if it prints 200.00000

Comment: i am not sure i understand you Bo why is *f=(float)(x[0]) any different than
    int y;
    f=3.5;
    y=(int)(f);
or
    float f;
    int y;
    y=255;
    f=(float)(y);

Answer (score 5):

First and foremost, `int` and `float` are not compatible types.

In your code, by saying

```
 f=(float*)(x);
```

you're breaking the [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98650/2173917). Any further usage invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To put in simple words, you cannot just take a pointer to a `float`, cast that to an `int *` and dereference that `int *` to get an `int` value. To quote the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing),

> [..] pointer arguments in a function are assumed to not alias if they point to fundamentally different types, [...]

For a much detailed description, please see the already linked *FAQ* answer.

Comment: f=(float*)(&x);
doesn't make a difference either right
could you explain a little more

Comment: Sorry for editing tags to remove C++ after you posted this answer! Culpa mea. Anyway, note that the Holy C++ Standard does not contain the term "strict aliasing". That's wholly a gcc notion, a particular compiler. Although it's strongly associated with a paragraph of the standard.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: It is "Mea Culpa". And the correct term would be "effective type", but the standard well mentions "aliasing". The "strict aliasing" you associate with gcc is another issue related to pointers. Note this is about C, not C++.

Comment: @Olaf: Are you **sure** that the [word order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_grammar) matters much in Latin?

Comment: @Sandman added tadbit of explanation here, see the linked answer, that's a goldmine. :)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: That's what I learned and I trust my old teacher more than Wikipedia. Also as a common phrase, there is some established order. But I will accept if that was some cultural difference.

Comment: While the term is commonly used, @Cheersandhth.-Alf is right in that the standard does not. See 6.5p6

Comment: @Olaf Are you suggesting the wording to be `incompatible effective type`? Will that be better?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: I agree it is not that snappy as "strict aliasing". The choice is yours:-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh Thanks i think i got it I see this undefined behavior because of the way float and int are stored and the same memory location/contents can't be just read off like that.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> printf("%f\n",*f); /*(1)why is this value 0.0*/
> ```

You are taking the address of an `int` and treating it like it contains a `float`. That is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%f\n",*f); /*(1)why is this value 0.0*/
```

This is effectively undefined behavior, but saying this doesn't explain why you have 0.0 in your case. The result could have been anything because it is undefined behavior, but with a given compiler and a given machine, the behavior, while not specified, produced something.

You are reading as a float a memory that contains the encoding of an int; it is highly probable that the encoding of 200 as int, is read as a very small value (a denormalized small float number) as a float and written as 0.0. On my machine, denormalized float numbers are printed as 0.0 with printf (don't know if it is a standard printf behavior).

For float encoding, read IEEE 754.